# parsing wsdl error: Unknown required WSDL extension 'http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl'

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have 3rd party local wsdl consisted from 6 .wsdl files and 14 .xsd files.

Every .wsdl file starts by string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions ... xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" ...
```

When I create soapClient like

```
$sc = new SoapClient($myLocalWsdlMainFile, [
    'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,//SOAP_1_2 getting same result
    'location' => $myLocation,
    'uri'      => $myUri,
    "trace" => 1,
    "exception" => 1,
]);
```

I get error at once

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Unknown required WSDL extension 'http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl'

What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread: https://github.com/phpro/soap-client/issues/20
It happens due to WSAW extension, which is not included by default in the SoapClient package. To get rid of this error, in .wsdl file change:

```
    <wsaw:UsingAddressing wsdl:required="true"/>
```

To:

```
    <wsaw:UsingAddressing wsdl:required="false"/>
```

Changing required ="false" worked alright for me!